# Can interface have inner classes or interfaces?

Tags: class, interface, inner

Can interface have inner classes or interfaces?
Looks like it is not possible and the answer is no, however it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_interfaces.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm

Can anyone explain why it is not mentioned in documentation and why this is not possible in Salesforce Apex?

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces in Apex is same like Interfaces in Java. I just googled and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921412/why-interface-can-not-implement-another-interface) question in stackoverflow.

The excerpt which i like to point is

> interface is meant to declare just to provide interface not for
>   implementation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create both an inner class or an inner interface inside a apex interface just like java.
the following compiles fine:

```
public interface A {
    class B {
    }
}
public interface A {
    interface B {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second example does not compile.